# perl CGI to write file to sibling directory

Tags: perl, directory, cgi

current folder structure is as follows

/main/site/script.cgi

I want to be able to write to a file at

main/logs/mylog.log

How can I do this without giving the absolute path ? since This can be deployed to different servers, I wont want to have to change this every time its deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a directory using a *relative* path, you need to establish first what that path will be relative *to*. That means you need to find out what the current working directory is for running CGI scripts.

If you add this program to your server and call it up on a browser you will see the current working directory that that server applies to all of its CGI programs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI ':standard';
use Cwd 'getcwd';

print header('text/plain');

printf "Current working directory: %s\n", getcwd;
```

If, for instance, you find that the current working directory is `/main/site` then you can create the file using the path `../logs/mylog.log`.